# Specific Swiper From Link From Other Page

Tags: swiper.js

I'm coding a website that is based around SWIPER JS (where each section of the page is a swiper slide, swiping vertically). The issue is that I have a nav with links to specific slides on other pages, and when I use a traditional link (eg. Link)the new page loads to the correct section and will swipe down but not up from that slide.

**Looking for a solution that works with SWIPER JS, ideally.**

Some Notes:

- After some testing, I've found that a traditional link loads the correct slide, but gives it an index of 0 instead of the correct one (for example 1).
- When I swipe all the way down through the final slide, SWIPER JS seems to reload and then reads that it's the final slide and then works fine (the animation is that of the pagination coming down from the top). *if someone can identify what function this is calling, this may work as the solution*

Answer (score 0):

I added "hashNavigation: true" from the API, as well as added "data-hash = "whichever" and everything seemed to work then.